# Ext.Ajax.request can't pass parameter to Spring controller in a POST request

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, extjs

On my server side project I have a method looking like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, path="mypath")
public String myMethod(String myString, Authentication authentication) {
    //Here myString is null!!!
}
```

On my client side program I try to call the method with this code:

```
var text="a long string...";
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'blablabla/mypath',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {myString: text},
    success: function(response, opts) { },
    failure: function(response, opts) { }
});
```

The problem is that the parameter myString becomes null when it gets to the server.

Comment: Apparently the param was too long

Comment: Did you try using get or inside some DTO?

Comment: Now I try with the GET. What is DTO?

Comment: Through DTO you dont need to add more params to this java api, its better way for programming. You can simply google "java dto".

Comment: So instead of params: {myString: text} what should I write?